# GIT: `error: unable to find <commit>` and `fatal: object <commit> not found` on pull

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull

We have a repo in Bitbucket, which we use as a central repo:

1. we update it via pull requests or directly by pushing changes, and
2. we synchronize the last changes in remote servers by pulling from it.

This has been working like a charm for about a year, but now we are not able to pull changes from this repo to update a remote server:

```
$ git pull origin
remote: Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unable to find a1354e341c6773997c31a109e615d1bf9acb0119
fatal: object a1354e341c6773997c31a109e615d1bf9acb0119 not found
```

Nonetheless, this object/commit is available from Bitbucket and also in my local machine (where I generated it and then pushed to the central repo).

I have been dealing with this issue for more than 8 hours. My knowledge of Git is barely enough to do basic things so I tried blindly a lot of possible solutions that worked for other people in the same situation that I found on the Web, but none of them has produced results. I tried things like:

```
$ git gc
$ git fsck --full
$ git reflog expire --expire=0 --all
```

I also reset to the previous state of the repo and re-apply the changes again but it didn't work either.

Any clue on this subjet?

**EDIT:**

Jonathan Swinney asked me what happens when I try to clone the repo. Well, it is kinda weird. If I clone it in my local machine it works OK but it won't work on a remote server via SSH:

```
$ git clone https://******@bitbucket.org/******/******.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/a/idpro/.git/
Password: 
remote: Counting objects: 19853, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7525/7525), done.
remote: Total 19853 (delta 12910), reused 15843 (delta 10336)
Receiving objects: 100% (19853/19853), 21.12 MiB | 6.00 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12910/12910), done.
error: refs/remotes/origin/master does not point to a valid object!
error: Trying to write ref refs/heads/master with nonexistant object c16203dc93b1557fc1d01102ea460663a8112e50
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'HEAD'.
```

You can notice that `c16203dc93b1557fc1d01102ea460663a8112e50` is not the same head as above (`a1354e341c6773997c31a109e615d1bf9acb0119`) since I pulled from another local repo and pushed the changes to the central one as part of my attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: What happens when you clone the repository from scratch?

Comment: @JonathanSwinney I answered in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a versioning problem. Once we updated our GIT versions it worked just right.

Answer (score 0):

sudo yum upgrade –skip-broken –y git

Then again do git –version and it should tell you something > 1.8

Then try the git pull origin .