# `git clone /DIRECTORY` versus `git clone file:///DIRECTORY`

Tags: git, shell

I have a problem with a `git clone` command. When I run

```
$ git clone /SOURCE_DIRECTORY /TARGET_DIRECTORY
```

Everything works fine and I get

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /TARGET_DIRECTORY/.git/
```

When I run this command (only `file://` added)

```
$ git clone file:///SOURCE_DIRECTORY /TARGET_DIRECTORY
```

I get

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /TARGET_DIRECTORY/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 737, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (189/189), done.
remote: Total 737 (delta 264), reused 725 (delta 256)
Receiving objects: 100% (737/737), 68.25 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (264/264), done.
error: Trying to write ref HEAD with nonexistant object XXXXXXXX
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'HEAD'.
```

Can anybody tell me, what's the difference between `/DIRECTORY` and `file:///DIRECTORY` and why I get a different result here?

Comment: Is it on a specific directory name or on any directory name?

Comment: I did not try "any" directory - but it's reproducible on any directory that I tried it (e.g. `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace`)

Comment: Please refer to  `Local Protocol` at `https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link to the [Git Docs](//git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#Local-Protocol) that [@ElpieKay](//stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay) commented with:

> Git operates slightly differently if you explicitly specify `file://` at the beginning of the URL. If you just specify the path, Git tries to use hardlinks or directly copy the files it needs. If you specify `file://`, Git fires up the processes that it normally uses to transfer data over a network which is generally a lot less efficient method of transferring the data. The main reason to specify the `file://` prefix is if you want a clean copy of the repository with extraneous references or objects left out – generally after an import from another version-control system or something similar

So the extra output that you see signifies the fact that Git is spinning up its network stack to transfer the data, instead of doing a local copy, as it does in your first example. Thus, unless you have a reason to use the network stack to transfer the data, it's better to drop the `file://`.

As for the error:

```
error: Trying to write ref HEAD with nonexistant object XXXXXXXX
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'HEAD'.
```

These answers indicate that this can be caused by using an older version of Git:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30119444/2747593
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13987696/2747593
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12091461/2747593

So try upgrading your Git client.

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer. The problem for me is, that I cannot "drop" the `file://` since this operations happens inside of a Maven command which I cannot easily influence. But now I know what to do next and will try a new Git version.

Comment: updating git did the trick - still wondering why everything worked two days ago and then "suddenly" stopped working...

Comment: Yeah I don't know what would cause it to break suddenly. Glad you got it fixed!